# Explain this code regarding AVR port setup

Tags: avr-gcc, bitmask

What does the following do?

```
PORTB = (PORTB & ~0xFC) | (b & 0xFC);
PORTD = (PORTD & ~0x30) | ((b << 4) & 0x30);
```

AFAIK, the 0xFC is a hex value. Is that basically saying 11111100, hence PORTD0-PORTD1 are outputs but the rest are inputs.

What would a full explanation of that code be?

Comment: I did not see any mention of bitwise operation in the original post and I see that Dave has added the bitwise-operations tag, but just to be clear here, the topic you are asking about is bitwise-operations and you should supplement any answer here with a google search of what these operators are (AND, OR, inverse, shift, etc).  Ignore this comment if you already know your C bitwise operators.

Answer (score 4):

> PORTB = (PORTB & ~0xfc) | (b & 0xfc);

Breaking it down:

```
PORTB = PORTB & ~0xFC

0xFC =  1111 1100
~0xFC = 0000 0011

PORTB = PORTB & 0000 0011
```

Selects the lower two bits of `PORTB`.

```
b & 0xFC

0xFC = 1111 1100
```

Selects the upper 6 bits of b.

ORing them together, `PORTB` will contain the upper six bits of b and the lower two bits of `PORTB`.

> PORTD = (PORTD & ~0x30) | ((b << 4) & 0x30);

Breaking it down:

```
PORTD = PORTD & ~0x30

0x30  = 0011 0000
~0x30 = 1100 1111

PORTD = PORTD & 11001111
```

Selects all but the 4th and 5th (counting from 0) bits of PORTD

```
(b << 4) & 0x30
```

Consider b as a field of bits:

```
b = b7 | b6 | b5 | b4 | b3 | b2 | b1 | b0

b << 4 = b3 b2 b1 b0 0 0 0 0

0x30 = 0011 0000

(b << 4) & 0x30 = 0 0 b0 b1 0 0 0 0
```

ORing the two pieces together, `PORTD` will contain the 0th and 1st bits of `b` in its 4th and 5th bits and the original values of PORTD in the rest.

Comment: maybe for a beginner, "Selects the lower two bits of PORTB" isn't clear enough?  I wonder if it's easier for people to understand if you say "Preserves the value of the lower two bits, but clears all of the remaining bits in PORTB".

Comment: I'm not sure which is clearer, I tend to think of AND as an operation which selects bits according to a mask.

Answer (score 0):

The first line actually sets the state of port's PB7-PB2 lines. The current state of PORTB is first masked using `~0xFC` = `0x03`, so all bits, but 0 and 1, are reset.

The second step is masking `b` using 0xFC, so bits 0 and 1 are always 0. Then the values are OR'ed together. Effectively, it sets PB7-PB2 from b[7]..b[2], while keeping the current state of PB1 and PB0 untouched.

Note, that the PORTB register bits serve different purposes depending on the pin direction configured via the DDRB register. For output pins, it simply controls the pin state. For input pins, PORTB controls the pin's pull-up resistor. You have to enable this pull-up resistor if, for example, you have a push button connected between the pin and ground - this way the input pin is not floating when the switch is open.